# Razor Syntax for Rendering Multiple Places from a single loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, loops, razor, foreach

Is there any way I can render a separate section from a single loop in a view? I have two div's that both need content from the same loop but are in different parts of the page. I don't want to have to loop twice if need be. Example:

```
<div id="content1">
@foreach (Item item in Model)
{
   <div>@item.ItemName</div>
}
</div>

<div id="content2">
@foreach (Item item in Model)
{
   <div>@item.ItemDescription</div>
}
</div>
```

The only way I can think of doing it is to build a string of the content and spit it out with Html.Raw:

```
<div id="content1">
@{
   StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(Item item in Model)
   {
      <div>@item.ItemName</div>

      html.AppendFormat("<div>{0}</div>", item.ItemDescription);
   }
</div>

<div id="content2">
    @Html.Raw(html.ToString())
</div>
}
```

Just wondered if there was a better way?

Comment: what's wrong with this? there's two sections, so it makes sense to have two loops.

Comment: @DLeh Basic performance no?

Comment: the performance difference would be so minimal that it wouldn't be worth trying to make something clever that would reuse a single loop. Whatever code you created would perform 0.1ms faster and would be much more confusing to future coders looking at it

Comment: I had the same issue, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="content1">
@foreach (Item item in Model)
{
   <div>@item.ItemName</div>
   <div class='content2'>@item.ItemDescription</div>
}
</div>

<div id="content2">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content2").detach().appendTo("#content2");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: will this remove content from `.content2` and append to `#content2` ? or the content still there is `.content2` ?

Comment: this will move all divs with class content2 to div with id content2